# Is it possible to run APC with PHP-CGI?

Tags: php, fastcgi, apc

Is it possible to run APC with PHP-CGI? I can't fetch the apc upload value for the uploaded files, the configuration i used is:

```
apc.rfc1867 On
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
```

The php code:

```
$status = apc_fetch('upload_'.$uid); // $uid = id for the file
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.apc-fetch.php#79321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. APC does not work when running as CGI -- it depends on sharing data with other processes, which only works when all the PHP processes are started up together. (This is only true when PHP is running as an Apache module, or under FastCGI / FPM.)